# Produce a plain page with only a message

Tags: pages

I am integrating a payment gateway into a distributed wordpress plugin.  The notification page (page that the gateway sends info to after the payment has been made) requires only a message of "success" or "fail" to be printed.  In that page, I need access to the database and some org options.  Can someone please tell me how to produce such a page (i.e. no menu, no header, no footer and etc.)?  The gateway in question is alipay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Just don't include `get_header()`, `get_siderbar()`, `get_footer()`.